# Bootstrap Navbar hover weirdness

Tags: hover, navbar, box

Im new. I would love to get some help with why you think this might be happening. Thanks!

So I'm creating a site for a family member's business but the bootstrap nav bar
has some background box when its "active" from ScrollSpy. Please note the background is suppose to be transparent.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fINse.gif)

Comment: Could you post the HTML and CSS corresponding to the navbar?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Thank you chrome for being able to temporarily disable css. It was due to Bootstrap's min css file with active modules, in what I couldnt edit due to my css not having it